# Join Eloquent Laravel Not Working ID Contains special character or alphabet

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been create join table with eager load , here i have 2 tables 
table **mutasi_logs** (child) and **transaction_details** (parent)

**Mutasi_logs structure :**

[image: table mutasi]

**Transaction_details structure**

[image: table trans detail]

table **mutasi_logs** has *transaction_detail_id* column foreign key that contain *id* from table **transaction_detail**

I've try join with eloquent like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MutasiLog extends Model
{

    public function transaction_detail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TransactionDetail::class, 'id','transaction_detail_id');
    }
}
```

and result array **transaction_detail** is NULL . I assumed because the **id** on the table **transaction_details** contains " **-** " ex : 123-31337 .. then i try to change it to *123* and working fine. but here i want save the **id** with 123-random numbers with contain "-"

Anyone can help me out about it ?

Comment: try to put this in your model public `$incrementing = false;` and this `protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name';`

Comment: [ SOLVED ] - thank you ... can u put it to answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this in your model public `$incrementing = false;` and this protected `$primaryKey = 'your_key_name';`

You can also refer to this [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351425/how-to-disable-laravel-eloquent-auto-increment) and try to read more about [Larave Docs Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)