# laravel controller how to insert an id without auto increment?

Tags: laravel, count, controller, insert

```
        $category = new HmsBbrCategory;
        $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
        $category->save();
        
        $category->category_id = $category->id;
        $category->save();
```

I have this table, only the `id` is set to not null. I need to insert the column WITHOUT using auto increment, what do I add to my function?

[image: 1]

I was thinking to count the id and just to add +1 so that the numbers are in squence:

```
$category->id = id()->count()+1;
```

This line is not counting though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fetch the last id from db

```
$categoryId=HmsBbrCategory::orderByDesc('id')->first();

$autoIncId=$categoryId->id+1;

$category = new HmsBbrCategory;
$category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
$category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
$category->id=$autoIncId;
$category->category_id =$autoIncId;
$category->save();
```

Comment: i see! so its orderByDesc, thanks again for answering, learned alot from you today

Answer (score 0):

You can try this based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351425/how-to-disable-laravel-eloquent-auto-increment)

```
//In your model
protected $primaryKey = 'key';
public $incrementing = false;

//Remove ID as primary key from migration
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();

//Then find latest ID by desc order and increment it before saving.
```