# Laravel 8 auto-increments columns even after setting the public $increments = false in model

Tags: mysql, eloquent, primary-key, laravel-8, auto-increment

I am trying to build a Laravel 8 CRUD application.

Here is my migration file, `2021_06_29_201031_create_books_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('book_title',100)->primary();
            $table->integer('book_pages');
            $table->integer('book_year_published',4);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

and my model file, `Book.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'books';
    protected $primaryKey = 'book_title';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'book_pages' => 'int',
        'book_year_published' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'book_pages',
        'book_year_published'
    ];
}
```

When I run the migration file, it is giving me the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `books` add primary key `books_book_title_primary`(`book_title`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I already looked at these answers but none of them are working:

1. [How to disable Laravel eloquent Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351425/how-to-disable-laravel-eloquent-auto-increment)
2. [Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1068-multiple-primary-key-defined)
3. [defining primary keys in migration](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/defining-primary-keys-in-migration)

I want a table named `books` that is equivalent to the following SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE books(
book_title VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
book_pages INT NOT NULL,
book_year_published INT(4) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: see if the table is already created in a before migration or just you're trying to reload over the same migration

Comment: @Prospero There are no tables in database. I just built the database and trying to run the migration.