# Laravel : insert random id on field have autoincrement id

Tags: laravel, insert, auto-increment

I have generate random id function :

```
class CreateRandomId {
    public static function get_id($my_table) {
        $id = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999999); 
        if(self::check_id($id,$my_table)){
            get_id($my_table);
        }
        return $id;
    }

    public static function check_id($id,$my_table) {
        $table=DB::table($my_table)->where('id',$id)->get();
        if (count($table)==0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I used it and it is generate id correctly but when i want to save it as id thus :

```
$new_user_id = CreateRandomId::get_id('users');   
    $user = User::create([
        'id' => $new_user_id,
        'social_id'=>$request->id, 
        'client'=> $request->client,  
        'username'=>$request->username,
        'password'=>$password,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'pics'=>$request->pics,
        'role'=>'user'
    ]);
```

It doesn't save the random id but the `auto_incrementid`

I view this topic [How to disable Laravel eloquent Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351425/how-to-disable-laravel-eloquent-auto-increment)
but I dont want to remove auto increment I just want to insert random data instead of it .

Comment: Make sure that 'id' is in the fillable section of your User Model

Comment: @dz0nika i think you are right I'll try many thanks

Comment: @dz0nika wouldnt that trigger a mass assignment exception. i think you need to set `public $increment = false;` in your model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Laravel eloquent Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351425/how-to-disable-laravel-eloquent-auto-increment)

Comment: Hm, if his ID field is setup to be incrementing then yes it will, but since he is putting RANDOM numbers as IDs i dont think thats the case, but still good catch

Comment: @N69S no it isnt helped me

Comment: @dz0nika I just missed to make id fillable as you mentioned it is work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets close this question, so as you said in the comments, the fix for this is to make the id field fillable so it looks something like this

```
protected $fillable = ['id', ...];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add your primary key in fillable array , and make increment to be false like this :-

```
public $increment = false;
protected $fillable = ['id',..];
```